# Using <s:url> and <s:a href> in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I have a JavaScript function that converted json value to string and populated table rows.

```
function onclickbuttonRef(searchVal) {
  Var sendData={ task: "ajaxCallRefINoteModal", searchVal: searchVal };
  $.post("InspectionRequestAction.action", sendData, function (data) {
  Var ary = jQuery.parseJSON(data) ;
  Var html = "";
  for(var i=0;I<ary.length;I++) {
  html += "<tr>"+
  "<td>"+
  "<input name='chkr' type='checkbox' onclick=\" javascript:onclickcheckRef('"+ary[i][0]+"','"+I+"')\"></td>"+
   "<td>"+
   "<s:url action=\" InspectionRequestAction\" includeParams=\"get\" method=\"edit\" var=\"temp\">"+
   "<s:param name=\"strPk\" value=\"%{"+ary[i][0]+"}\" />"+"</s:url>"+
   "<s:a href=\"%{#temp}\" >"+ary[i][0]+"</s:a></td>"+
   "<td>"+ary[i][1]+"</td>"+
   "<td>"+ary[i][2]+"</td>"+
   "<td>"+ary[i][3]+"</td>"+
   "</tr>";
   }
   $("#reftablebody").html(html) ;
   }) ;
```

The checkbox and the table body is correctly generated and displayed but the <s:url> and <s:a href> doesn't work. The value of the ary[i][0] is simply displayed, no hyperlink or action invocation happens.
I have set the value of struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation to true as well as struts.devMode to true in my struts. Xml.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

JSP tags are executed on the server, before anything is sent to the client.

JS is executed on the client. Your code tries building server-side tags in JavaScript, at which point it's too late--the browser doesn't have any idea what an S2 tag is or what to do with it.

This is a surprisingly (and confusingly) common mistake.

In your case you'll probably need to duplicate what the S2 tags *would* render if they worked the way you thought they did, which would mean building up your parameters for the HTML URL.